# SQL Query - Summing new variable created

Tags: sql

I have a table containing claims and I want to have a query that returns to me how many claims I have per Sales Month `SalesDt` (`202102`).

However, I want to have this count splitted per one variable that I'm also creating on the query based on `UsePeriod` (quantity of days that customer has his part failed), Since I'm insterested only how many year the customer has this part, I divide `UsePeriod` per 365 (I call this new variable as `YIS`)

What I want to get

[image]

Follow the SQL Code:

```
SELECT CONCAT(datepart (yy,SalesDt), FORMAT (SalesDt,'MM')) AS 'SalesYM'
    ,SUM(
        CASE WHEN CONCAT(STR(CEILING(UsePeriod/365)+1),'YIS') = '1YIS' 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END) AS '1YIS'
    ,SUM(
       CASE WHEN CONCAT(STR(CEILING(UsePeriod/365)+1),'YIS') = '2YIS' 
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
       END) AS '2YIS'
FROM [Claim] AS C
LEFT JOIN [Type] AS T
ON C.Code = T.Code
WHERE T.Prod='TR'
GROUP BY CONCAT(datepart (yy,SalesDt), FORMAT (SalesDt,'MM'))
ORDER BY CONCAT(datepart (yy,SalesDt), FORMAT (SalesDt,'MM'))
```

With the code, I got the results below:

[image]

I dont understand why the code is not summing correctly

Comment: I think you could change:
CASE WHEN CONCAT(STR(CEILING(UsePeriod/365)+1),'YIS') = '1YIS' 
for:
CASE WHEN UsePeriod > 0 AND UsePeriod < 365
It is more simple and maybe works better.

Comment: There are no *variables* in the code above

Comment: @MundoPeter, it has worked, thank you for your help

Comment: @RafaelRodriguesSantos, great! I posted it as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: Product specific query, which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it this way:

```
SELECT CONCAT(datepart (yy,SalesDt), FORMAT (SalesDt,'MM')) AS 'SalesYM'
    ,SUM(
        CASE WHEN UsePeriod > 0 AND UsePeriod <= 365
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END) AS '1YIS'
    ,SUM(
       CASE WHEN UsePeriod > 365 AND UsePeriod <= (2 * 365)
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
       END) AS '2YIS'
FROM [Claim] AS C
LEFT JOIN [Type] AS T
ON C.Code = T.Code
WHERE T.Prod='TR'
GROUP BY CONCAT(datepart (yy,SalesDt), FORMAT (SalesDt,'MM'))
ORDER BY CONCAT(datepart (yy,SalesDt), FORMAT (SalesDt,'MM'))
```